# Can mobs drop special items?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I suddenly found an enchanted bow with Power I in my inventory. I did not craft it myself since I don't have an enchantment table. I'm playing on a private server with 2-3 friends and none of them made one either. And I'm pretty sure I did not find it in a chest somewhere. I just randomly found it. Lucky me! Now I would like to know where it came from :)

- Can mobs drop special items?
- If so, at what rate does it happen?

Answer (score 14):

Zombies, skeletons and zombie pigmen each have a 2.5% chance of dropping a rare drop, if they drop, there is a 20% chance of it having an enchantment which would cost 5 levels in a enchanting table. Using a sword with the looting enchatement increases these chances.

Skeletons can drop bows, zombies can drop iron tools, helmets or ingots and zombie pigmen drop gold tools, helments or ingots.

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Rare_drops#Rare_drops)

Comment: I've never seen a zombie drop any tool except shovel. It's just helmets, ingots and shovels.

Comment: Yeah, they only drop shovels. I know because I filled an entire double chest full of iron shovels from my zombie exp farm and never once got any other tool.

Comment: Later updates have made zombies properly drop tools other than shovels.

Comment: To add to @SevenSidedDie's comment, the only thing I've seen zombies drop is bows.

Answer (score 0):

It could have happened is a friend fished it and didn't pick it up. This will sound weird if you haven't heard it before, but I got a leather can, 2 wooden sword and a wooden pick by fishing once! It's way more likely you will get fish though. And I have never seen someone fish something enchanted... still sorta funny, fishing hats!

Comment: This sounds like a fishing story.