# In minecraft I found a zombie with an iron enchanted shovel but my brother never made one

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

A couple of hours ago, zombies invaded my camp and killed me. A minute later I found my camp and there was a zombie with an enchanted iron shovel. The weird thing is that I don't have a shovel and don't have a enchanting table either, so, where did the zombie pick it up from?

Comment: This question appears to be of a non-serious nature, and cannot as such be answered properly.

Comment: @LpSamuelm, I'd say it's just someone who just doesn't know that mobs can spawn in with enchanted items. Still, probably a dupe of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79838/ (Though, that's more about mobs dropping enchanted items, this seems to be about the later-added fact that they can spawn with them equipped, and drop things they were carrying)

Comment: what do you mean non serious nature?

Comment: @anthony If you mention herobrine the people here seem to freak out and dismiss the question.

Comment: oh, ok then take back the herobrine part

Comment: I saw "Could it have been Herobrine's?" as the main question. In hindsight, that was probably not it. @BillyMailman makes a good point.

Comment: no, were the zombie picked it up was the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Zombies sometimes spawn with random items in their hands or armor equipped to their bodies, they may or may not drop said items when they die.